# Apache Derby database extremely slow updating records when there is a foreign key

Tags: java, database, derby

I am updating 2500 records' String primary key using the direct sql below (run from java):

update childtable set column = 'new value' where column = 'old value'

I also have a parent table with the same string column and the child table has a foreign key to the parent table (childtable.column -> parenttable.column).

What I see is that running the above sql statement on 2500 rows takes consistently around 6 seconds and 300 milliseconds.  I have also tested and verified that it takes this long to perform this operation in some test scenarios using an external database tool (Squirrel).

If I do only one of any of the following, the runtime of the above sql goes to 400 milliseconds or so always.
-remove the foreign key from the child to the parent
-add an index on the child table on the child table's single column primary key and the column in the child table being referenced in the foreign key.  Ie this is a composite index on 2 columns.

I am satisfied with the fix of adding a composite index, but this fix doesn't work anymore in a more complicated example where the child table has a composite primary key which includes the column that references the parent table and there is a foreign key still on this column.

I would like to know how I can improve the performance of this scenario.  I am expecting that it should not be this slow to perform this update 400 ms to 6300 ms is a huge performance loss for something that should be simple in my mind.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a bad query plan, particularly since changing the keying makes a big difference. Here's background material about how to dig into Derby's performance behaviors: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips

Comment: Thanks but I tried all that and there seems to be nothing useful.  The query plans both obtained by setting the runtime parameters and comparing derby.log and the ones using code properties show that both query plans are exactly identical except the runtimes.  They are literally exactly the same I did a diff except for lines like the following:

Comment: next time (milliseconds) = 13
   close time (milliseconds) = 5
   projection time (milliseconds) = 0

Comment: You've confirmed that adding the index makes the performance improve, but **nothing** changes in the query plan output when you run the second experiment with the extra index and the improved performance?

Comment: that is correct.  I have timing code around the stmt and it takes ~7 sec longer to run yet there is nothing in the execution plan that is different aside from the mentioned milliseconds stats, I even tried running the query in Squirrel and it takes around the same time (ends up failing) because I'm only doing one part of the update (sql I mentioned) but the foreign key is deferred so it will fail on commit.  I also tried running the sql outside of Hibernate and Spring dao transactions and using the connection directly (sorry forgot to mention that) and it takes about 8 seconds to run that way.

Comment: Another strange thing is that having the fk but removing columns from the table will after a certain point get the same performance benefit as not having the fk, but the columns removed have nothing to do with the fk.  It also seems somewhat random as to what columns can be removed to improve the performance.  Ie. I can achieve the same speed increase by removing different columns.  This makes me think it's more about the width (number of columns) in the table which doesn't make much sense.  IO issue?  But then why doesn't it show up in the statistics or query plan?

Comment: Perhaps it's an external factor, for example a question of whether the file pages in question happen to be present in the operating system's filesystem cache at the time that you run your benchmark? Alternatively, you might try looking at a low-level Java application profiler to see if you can characterize any other behavioral differences between slow runs and fast runs. Or try a system-level tool like strace (on Linux) or Process Monitor (on Windows) to get a feel for any system-level differences between runs.